# My eventhub is continously receiving empty messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Azure event hub is receiving empty messages constantly. I checked all my publishes and am sure I am not publishing them.
How do know where are they coming from ?
I have a azure function trigger that prints nothing.
C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message:

PSB for snapshot of the Azure function monitor:
[Function Trigger Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRN0X.png)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: There is no code to post. Created an Azure Event Hub. Then created an Azure function trigger for the above Event HUB. I receive calls with Empty messages. I do not know who publishes them. C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use SAS based publisher policy with Event Hubs. Refer to below document for details -

[Event Hubs authentication and security model overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-authentication-and-security-model-overview)

Comment: We are using SAS. It seems like a bug. I even tried creating a new hub. This issue exists.